# Logrotate fails with error "unknown option 'I'" on Docker container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, logrotate

I have a Ruby on Rails application running on Docker and would like to rotate my production logs every day. In the spirit of keeping everything self-contained, I would like to keep the log rotation on Docker itself as well. Here's the logrotate configuration on my Docker container:

**/etc/logrotate.conf**

```
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# keep 1 week worth of backlogs
rotate 1

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# use date as a suffix of the rotated file
dateext

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress

# packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# system-specific logs may be also be configured here.

# Rotate Rails logs
/myapp/log/*.log {
  daily
  missingok
  rotate 7
  compress
  delaycompress
  notifempty
  copytruncate
}
```

Permissions for /etc/logrotate.conf:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 656 Jul 13 02:06 /etc/logrotate.conf
```

After a day, my log file has not been rotated. I know this isn't an issue with my container being recreated because it's been running for 6 days.

When I go to test it, I get an error message on every line:

```
> logrotate -d /myapp/log/production.log
  ...
> error: production.log:56257 unknown option 'I' -- ignoring line
> error: production.log:56258 unknown option 'I' -- ignoring line
> error: production.log:56259 unknown option 'I' -- ignoring line
```

Here are the permissions on my production.log:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10868754 Jul 14 12:42 /myapp/log/production.log
```

And when I check what's in the log file, the contents are indeed there:

```
I, [2022-07-13T02:48:23.666904 #1]  INFO -- : Raven 3.1.0 ready to catch errors
I, [2022-07-13T03:00:18.483790 #8]  INFO -- : Raven 3.1.0 ready to catch errors
I, [2022-07-13T03:00:34.021416 #22]  INFO -- : Started GET "/healthcheck" for xxx.xx.xx.xx at 2022-07-13 03:00:34 +0000
I, [2022-07-13T03:00:34.026047 #22]  INFO -- : Processing by HealthcheckController#show as HTML
I, [2022-07-13T03:00:34.027170 #29]  INFO -- : Started GET "/healthcheck" for xxx.xx.xx.xx at 2022-07-13 03:00:34 +0000
I, [2022-07-13T03:00:34.031331 #29]  INFO -- : Processing by HealthcheckController#show as HTML
I, [2022-07-13T03:00:34.038132 #20]  INFO -- : Started GET "/healthcheck" for xxx.xx.xx.xx at 2022-07-13 03:00:34 +0000
I, [2022-07-13T03:00:34.042771 #20]  INFO -- : Processing by HealthcheckController#show as HTML
I, [2022-07-13T03:00:34.040177 #20]  INFO -- : Started GET "/healthcheck" for xxx.xx.xx.xx at 2022-07-13 03:00:34 +0000
I, [2022-07-13T03:00:34.221546 #20]  INFO -- : Processing by HealthcheckController#show as HTML
```

What can I do to get `logrotate` to rotate my logs?

Comment: You have to pass the configuration `/etc/logrotate.conf` as an argument rather than the log file when running your debug command: `logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf`.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Ahh thank you! Looks like there was no issue with my config. I forced logrotate to start, it worked! [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46365627/2430657) revealed that `cron` isn't running on my Docker container, so I need to start it.

Comment: Don't do that, it is not a good idea to have systemd and crond on a container! Rather do what should be with containers, send your stdin/stderr, so Docker will handle them and implement a log driver on the machine that supports your Docker. https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/docker-logging/

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Thank you for the information; I will look into it. What if my application has regularly scheduled background jobs that rely on cron for scheduling? Should that be handled by an external cron service?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @β.εηοιτ.βε, I found out that I needed to specify the config file, not the log file, in the logrotate arguments when debugging it, like this:

```
logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf
```

That revealed there was nothing wrong with my configuration. Then I forced a log rotation with:

```
logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.conf
```

And it worked! As for why my log file was not rotated after a day, [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46323978/logrotate-nginx-logs-not-rotating-inside-docker-container/46365627#46365627) suggested that cron may not be running in the container, which I found out to be true in my case:

```
> service cron status
[FAIL] cron is not running ... failed!
```

I updated my Dockerfile's entrypoint to start `cron`. So it looks like this now:

**Dockerfile**

```
...

CMD /bin/bash

ENTRYPOINT [ "./docker/web-entrypoint.sh" ]
```

**docker/web-entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

if [ -f tmp/pids/server.pid ]; then
  rm tmp/pids/server.pid
fi

cron service start # New line added
bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000
```

Now it's all working!